# My C program CPU usage goes to 80% when redirecting to /dev/null

Tags: linux, c

I wrote a C program that operates with UDP sockets and the serial port `/dev/ttyS1` on uClinux. If I start the program normally as `./program` the CPU usage is around 24%. However, if I start the program with `./program >> /dev/null` the CPU usage jumps to 80%!

I have a lot of debugging `printf`s that are spewing out, how can redirecting to `/dev/null` quadruple the CPU usage?

Comment: 24% and 80% CPU usage strongly suggests your program is busy-looping. You should redesign it. It uses much less CPU then (presumably 0.1%) and the system gets faster overall. Also, your program isn't found uncooperative and thus, downrated by the scheduler.

Comment: Is it doing a lot of processing?

Comment: @Janka It doesn't suggest anything one way or another. Is `yes(1)` busy-looping? No, it's using blocking writes, and in most usage patterns will use 0% cpu. But if you redirect its output to `/dev/null` it won't have to wait and will go 100%: `yes >>/dev/null & top -p $!`.

Comment: *yes* is designed to do output on stdout and you are redirecting the stdout to /dev/null. The OPs program revolves around UDP sockets and /dev/ttyS1. The stdout blocking is the only thing what makes it block. Taking away that piece by redirecting it to >/dev/null makes CPU go up to 80%. Conclusion: The other part of the program is busy-looping.

Comment: I narrowed it down to my readSerial function(). I use select() but even with a timeout it is busy looping a lot. I am using non-blocking tty, but may change it to blocking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That’s usually an indication that your program is spending a significant amount of time waiting for its output to be handled. Waiting for I/O is counted separately from CPU usage. By redirecting its output to `/dev/null`, you eliminate that, and your program spends more time working.

Comment: Agree: If process has no Input/Output/Wait, then it will run at 100% CPU.

Comment: Thank you, this is really a real eye-opener in how much printfs() take to process and be displayed!